# Trigger DataTable highlight and filter base on input change

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, datatable, html-table

## Description

I have a table

```
<table id="account-table" class="table display nowrap" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead>
    <tr class="text-left">
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>Type</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Email Address</th>
      <th>Action</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

Here is my search input box

```
<input type="text" class="form-control mb20" id="search" placeholder="Search">
```

---

## Attempt

I've tried this settings

```
**include**

<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.10/features/searchHighlight/dataTables.searchHighlight.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://bartaz.github.io/sandbox.js/jquery.highlight.js"></script>



**settings**

$('#account-table').DataTable({
    data: data,
    deferRender: true,
    paging: true,
    searching: true,
    bLengthChange : false,
    Filter: false,
    Info:false,
    searchHighlight:true,
    iDisplayLength: 10,
});


**trigger the draw while typing**

$('#search').keyup(function(){
  $('#account-table').search($(this).val()).draw();
});
```

I'm not sure why my search functionality is not working when I start typing the search input box.

There is 0 error in the console.

How can I debug this?

Comment: did you try var table = $('#account-table).DataTable(); then $('#search').on( 'keyup', function () {
    table.search( this.value ).draw();
} );

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You shouldn't need to create your own search box, as datatable will create one for you above the table.

Are you seeing one generated called: `<input type="search" class="" placeholder="" aria-controls="account-table">`?

Here's a JSFiddle with all your code and with a working filter and highlight: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mhxqjdjh/1/)

If you DO need to use your own search box, then use

```
$('#search').keyup(function(){
  $('#account-table').DataTable().search($(this).val()).draw();
});
```

The reason it wasn't working was because `$('#account-table')` returns jQuery's results from its search for elements matching that selector - and DOM elements don't have functions called `search` on them. Calling `.DataTable()` on it causes DataTable to return the table object that produced that DOM table.

Comment: So basically, my mistake is only forgot to add this `.DataTable().`

Comment: @ihue Essentially yes :)

Comment: Plus, I create my owned search box so I can easily style and place them anywhere of my application.